# SSRS multiple reports single solution

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I need to run a report once a month, every month and once a quarter, every quarter. The underlying data for both reports is the same. Do I need to maintain a separate ssrs solution for each rdl file so that I can customize the start date and end date parameter defaults or is there some way that I can keep both rdl files in the same solution, have a monthStartDate and monthEndDate parameter that only the monthly report references and a quarterStartDate and quarterEndDate parameter?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shared, I'm not clear on why this even needs to be different reports (.rdl files.) One .rdl could take a `start` and `end` parameters and the subscriptions could be set up with different values for quarterly and monthly. Or another parameter could be added, `MonthOrQuarter` that changed variable values for the dataset or filters.

But certainly, this could be two `.rdl`'s referring to a shared dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that calculates the start and end of the various time periods you want based on the current date, and has a label that you can use as a parameter label

```
CREATE VIEW DateRangeParameters
AS
SELECT 
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', getdate()), '2000-01-01') AS  StartDate, 
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', getdate())+1, '2000-01-01') AS EndDate, 
'This Month' as Label
UNION ALL
SELECT
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', getdate())-1, '2000-01-01') AS 
StartDate, 
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', getdate()), '2000-01-01') AS EndDate, 
'LastMonth' as Label
UNION ALL
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '2000-01-01', getdate()), '2000-01-01') AS  StartDate, 
DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, '2000-01-01', getdate())+1, '2000-01-01') AS EndDate, 
'This quarter' as Label
UNION ALL
SELECT
DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, '2000-01-01', getdate())-1, '2000-01-01') AS 
StartDate, 
DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, '2000-01-01', getdate()), '2000-01-01') AS EndDate, 
'LastQuarter' as Label
```

Extend for any other time periods that you need week, year etc.

Create one dataset using this view directly to allow choosing a date range.

Link your the view with your existing query using >= start and < end date columns add a WHERE clause that links the label to your report parameter.

This way using your parameter will select which time range to use in your query.

You can then either run the reports manually and select the time range parameter, or schedule the report to run monthly and separately, schedule it to run quarterly. In each time select the appropriate parameter, which will dynamically calculate the appropriate date range.